# Is processes threads (or whole process) suspended

Tags: c#, multithreading, process

I would like to check if the processes' threads (the whole process) are suspended.
I'm obtaining each process thread by this code:

```
var threads = Proc.Threads;
for (int x = 0; x < threads.Count; x++) {
var thread = threads[x];
```

However `System.Diagnostics.ThreadState` doesn't contain `Suspended`, but `System.Threading.ThreadState` does. How do I convert `System.Diagnostics.ThreadState` to `System.Threading.ThreadState`, or is it some other method to check it? I'm not trying to suspend/resume them, just I want to know how Process hacker/Process explorer does that.

Comment: System.Threading's one is good enough, surely? What are you trying to do?  In diagnostics on MSDN it says "The thread state enumerations are only of interest in a few debugging scenarios. Your code should never use thread state to synchronize the activities of threads."  Diagnostics in general isn't what you should be using for actually dealing with threads

Comment: An operating system thread isn't the same as a .Net thread. `Process.Threads` returns OS threads, each of which may or may not correspond to a .Net thread. You can look at [`ProcessThread.WaitReason`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processthread.waitreason.aspx), but it doesn't correspond to .Net wait states.

Comment: @Matthew Watson if you will write this as an answer I'll approve it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Microsoft made a big mistake in .NET version 1.0, they added the Thread.Suspend() and Resume() methods.  Those methods were widely abused, programmers used them to implement thread synchronization.  For which they are entirely inappropriate.  Problem was that it *usually* worked.  But call Suspend() at an unlucky time and you'll freeze a thread while it is buried inside a Windows call, holding a global lock.  And causing the entire program to deadlock.

It was not the only design mistake they made, the Synchronized method on the collection classes was quite a disaster as well.  Widely misinterpreted as "returns a thread-safe collection".

Live and learn, this all got fixed in .NET 2.0.  One big overhaul was that a Thread may not necessarily be an operating system thread anymore, that never actually got implemented.  But explains why there are *two* ThreadState enumerations, one for Thread (the .NET version) and another for ProcessThread (the operating system version).  And they closed the loophole on programmers abusing Suspend/Resume, the methods were declared obsolete.  And they closed the backdoor as well, you can't find out from ProcessThread that a thread is suspended.

Feature, not a bug.  Don't make the same mistake, knowing that a thread is suspended is useless knowledge, it may well not be suspended anymore a microsecond later.

Comment: +1 - I do love to hear about .NET thread support cockups - it makes my own seem less worrisome:)

Answer (score 3):

This will help someone.

```
        Process proc = Process.GetProcessById(31448);
        if(proc.Threads[0].WaitReason == ThreadWaitReason.Suspended)
        {
            //process is suspended
        }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

An operating system thread isn't the same as a .Net thread. Process.Threads returns OS threads, each of which may or may not correspond to a .Net thread.

You can look at ProcessThread.WaitReason, but it doesn't correspond to .Net wait states

Answer (score 0):

You could improperly use [SuspendThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/windows/desktop/ms686345(v=vs.85).aspx) or Wow64SuspendThread to find out if it was suspended, then use [ResumeThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/windows/desktop/ms685086(v=vs.85).aspx) to restore the situation.

SuspendThread return: "If the function succeeds, the return value is the thread's previous suspend count;"

Declarations:

```
    [Flags] public enum ThreadAccess : int {
        TERMINATE = (0x0001),
        SUSPEND_RESUME = (0x0002),
        GET_CONTEXT = (0x0008),
        SET_CONTEXT = (0x0010),
        SET_INFORMATION = (0x0020),
        QUERY_INFORMATION = (0x0040),
        SET_THREAD_TOKEN = (0x0080),
        IMPERSONATE = (0x0100),
        DIRECT_IMPERSONATION = (0x0200)}

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr OpenThread(
        ThreadAccess dwDesiredAccess,
        bool bInheritHandle,
        uint dwThreadId);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern uint SuspendThread(IntPtr hThread);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern int ResumeThread(IntPtr hThread);

    [DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)] 
        static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);
```

(Wow64SuspendThread link hidden because i need 10 reputation to put over 2 links = ht.tps://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/windows/desktop/ms687400(v=vs.85).aspx)